# Is this possible to show mapView on dialogBox android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-alertdialog

Is this possible to show MapView on a Dialog in android and perform action like select a location to get latitude lonngitude for parent activity in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MapView is a view and if you set the ContentView of the dialog you will get a MapView in the Dialog.

Comment: This does not tell me anything about **WHAT** failed. **BE SPECIFIC**.

Answer (score 0):

I think Yes, make your MapActivity and add theme like Dialog in your activity tag in manifest file..

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```